# Download page for niDAQmx base does no longer list macos?

Tags: macos, labview, nidaqmx

every page about niDAQmx Base on macos x refers to this URL

http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-base-15.0/5648/en/

which no longers provides an OS popup to pick Mac as an option. Is mac support gone, or is has the page moved to another URL ?

Comment: Ask this at ni.com.

Comment: NI-DAQmx Base is not the same as NI-DAQmx: http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/53329/en/ It looks like some recent changes to the NI website forgot to take this into account. I've reported this at https://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-DAQmx-Base-Developers/NI-DAQmx-Base-for-LabVIEW-2017-on-Mac-OS-X/gpm-p/3651694

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some changes to how NI is planning on supporting DAQmx on OSX moving forward. The links from their [knowledge pages](http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/3217/en/) now point to the [DAQmx Base installation](http://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/drivers/download.ni-daqmx-base.html).
The [link provided by JKSH](http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/53329/en/) seems to have been updated to reflect this as well.